# Mono IDE on Windows

Tags: ide, mono

Is there any IDE for coding mono on windows platform?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MonoDevelop has now released a installer for Windows. You no longer need to build it from source. It is available from [the MonoDevelop website](http://monodevelop.com/Download/Windows_Preview)

However on windows it runs on the .NET Framework, not Mono - it uses the .NET debugger instead of the Mono one.

Answer (score 9):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) and Visual Studio will both work. You can also use the Windows version of [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/).

Comment: No installer exists for mono develop on windows.

Comment: @Daniel: No installer, but you can make it run. More info here: http://www.monodevelop.com/MonoDevelopWin32

Comment: Hey Trampster (comment above), now there is an installer for MD on windows, [here:](http://monodevelop.com/Download) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [#develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) or check out the status of porting [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/MonoDevelopWin32) (A fork of #develop) back to Windows.

Answer (score 2):

SharpDevelop comes to mind... I've found this quick howto for setting up a development environment with it and Mono and windows:
http://yacoding.blogspot.com/2006/04/howto-mono-sharpdevelop-and-firebird.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Delphi Prism 2010